# How to find specific path using Odoo 10 Xpath

Tags: xpath, odoo, odoo-9

```
    <group>
        <field name="tax_id" widget="many2many_tags" domain="[('type_tax_use','=','sale'),('company_id','=',parent.company_id)]"
            attrs="{'readonly': [('qty_invoiced', '&gt;', 0)]}"/>
        <label for="customer_lead"/>
        <div>
            <field name="customer_lead" class="oe_inline"/> days
        </div>
        <label for="analytic_tag_ids"/>
        <div>
            <field name="analytic_tag_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>
        </div>
    </group>
</group>
############WANT TO INSERT HERE
<label for="name"/>
<field name="name"/>
<div groups="base.group_no_one">
    <label for="invoice_lines"/>
    <field name="invoice_lines"/>
</div>
<field name="state" invisible="1"/>
```

This is in `sale_view.xml`

I have tried

```
xpath expr="//label[@for='name'//field name='name']" position='before'
```

and also tried various other paths and the full path too

```
/odoo/record[7]/field[3]/form/sheet/notebook/page[1]/field[1]/form/group
```

and

```
/odoo/record[7]//form[2]/group
```

I do not understand why it cannot find this path and why does not accept a string as selector.

**EDIT:**

```
<record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <xpath expr="//form//form//label[@for='name']" position="before">
        <div groups="base,group_no_one">
          <label for="l_ids"/>
          <field name="l_ids"/>
        </div>
      </xpath>
      <field name="partner_id" position="after">
        <button name="abc" string="abc" type="object"
                class="oe_inline fa fa-arrow-right oe_link"/>
      </field>
    </field>
  </record>
```

This is the Error:

```
Error context:
View `sale.order form`
[view_id: 687, xml_id: promo.view_order_form, model: sale.order, parent_id: 508]
2016-11-07 06:43:03,556 22642 CRITICAL odoo10 odoo.service.server: Failed to initialize database `odoo10`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maharshi/workspace/odoo-10.0/odoo/service/server.py", line 898, in preload_registries
    registry = Registry.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
  File "/home/maharshi/workspace/odoo-10.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 78, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/maharshi/workspace/odoo-10.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 333, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/home/maharshi/workspace/odoo-10.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 235, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/home/maharshi/workspace/odoo-10.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 177, in load_module_graph
    env['ir.ui.view']._validate_module_views(module_name)
  File "/home/maharshi/workspace/odoo-10.0/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1171, in _validate_module_views
    self.raise_view_error("Can't validate view:\n%s" % (e.message or repr(e)), vid)
  File "/home/maharshi/workspace/odoo-10.0/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 445, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Can't validate view:
External ID must be fully qualified

Error context:
View `sale.order form`
```

This is the problem with most of the path i have tried to use.

Comment: Your div groups is wrong. It should be "base.group_no_one".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```xml
<label for="name" position="before">
    <!-- your xml here -->
</label>
```

or

```xml
<xpath expr="//form//form//label[@for='name']" position="before">
    <!-- your xml here -->
</xpath>
```

**Edit**:

Your `record` should look something like this:

```xml
<record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">my.sale.order.form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <!-- one of the above here -->
    </field>
</record
```

Comment: Have tried both already... it says for the first one `External ID must be fully qualified` and for the second one it cannot find the path.

Comment: Can you please give us the full xml record in your question? Maybe there is another mistake anywhere.

Comment: Yes i have edited the question and added the xml record and error trackback.